# Where this $2\pi$ came from?

Tags: physics

In this [link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/12%3A_Sources_of_Magnetic_Fields/12.03%3A_Magnetic_Field_due_to_a_Thin_Straight_Wire) there are this equation (12.3.2): $B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{wire}\frac{I\sin{\theta}dx}{r^2}$. And is said to substitute $r$ by $\sqrt{x^2+R^2}$ and $\sin{\theta}$ by $\frac{R}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}$.

This part is easy.

$B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{wire}\frac{I\frac{R}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}dx}{(\sqrt{x^2+R^2})^2} \Rightarrow B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{wire}\frac{I\frac{R}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}}dx}{x^2+R^2} \Rightarrow B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{wire}I\frac{Rdx}{\sqrt{x^2+R^2}(x^2+R^2)}$

$B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{wire}I\frac{Rdx}{(x^2+R^2)^\frac{1}{2}(x^2+R^2)^1} \Rightarrow B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{wire}I\frac{Rdx}{(x^2+R^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$

This last equation above is equal to the right side of the equation (12.3.5) in this same [link](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/12%3A_Sources_of_Magnetic_Fields/12.03%3A_Magnetic_Field_due_to_a_Thin_Straight_Wire), but for some reason $4\pi$ came to be $2\pi$, I sincerely don't know where this $2\pi$ came from, someone can explain me this?

Comment: "The wire is symmetrical about point O, so we can set the limits of the integration from zero to infinity and double the answer, rather than integrate from negative infinity to positive infinity."

Comment: @eyeballfrog You have to be more clear, what you are trying to say? That by setting the limits of a integration I can multiplie certain part of a equation? 
And that $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}$ is the answer? What is an answer in a equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically, the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{R}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}} $$
is symmetric around $x = 0,$ that is, if you look at the graph from $x=-\infty$ to $x=0$ it is the exact mirror image of the graph from $x=0$ to $x=\infty,$
and the areas under the two curves are equal:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
 = \int_0^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}.$$
This is something you can confirm with a simply change of variable from $x$ to $-x.$

But it is also supported by the physical intuition stated immediately after Equation $(12.3.2)$: the wire is symmetric around the point $O$
(and more importantly, though it is not said explicitly,
the wire is symmetric around the line $OP$).
Therefore any field that is contributed by the left half of the wire is just exactly the same as the field contributed by the right half.

To continue in excruciating detail:

$$
\begin{align}
B &= \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_\text{wire}\frac{I\sin\theta\,\mathrm dx}{r^2} 
&& \text{Equation $(12.3.2)$}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\int_\text{wire}\frac{\sin\theta\,\mathrm dx}{r^2} 
&& \text{$I$ is a constant factor}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\int_\text{wire}\frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}} 
&& \sin\theta = \dfrac{R}{\sqrt{x^2 + R^2}}, \  r^2 = x^2 + R^2\\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}} 
&& \text{Wire from $x=-\infty$ to $x=\infty$}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\left(
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
+ \int_0^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
\right)
&& \\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\left(
\int_0^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
+ \int_0^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
\right)
&& \text{Symmetry of the integral}\\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{4\pi}\left(2
\int_0^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
\right)
&& \\
&= \frac{\mu_0 I}{2\pi}
\int_0^\infty \frac{R\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2 + R^2)^{3/2}}
&& \text{Cancel a factor of $2$}\\
\end{align}
$$

and *voilá*, you have Equation $(12.3.5).$

Comment: Honestly from equation (12.3.2) to equation (12.3.5) its not very detailed and before you answer it sounded like magic to me, because they don't even explain why they removed $I$ from the integration. They explain that is constant in a page before in another equation, so if I wouldn't know it, I would struggle to figure it out. Well thanks for the answer, is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

When you have an even function $f$ over the real line, assuming (absolute) integrability, you have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\;dx = 2\int_0^\infty f(x)\;dx
$$
In your context, take
$$
f(x)=\frac{C}{(x^2+R^2)^{3/2}},\quad C=\frac{\mu_0IR}{4\pi}\;.
$$

Comment: I think that the right side of the first equation makes sense, because this integration is equal to the integration in the equation (12.3.5) of the link, but I don't get the second equation. This makes sense to you? $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}2\int_0^\infty{f(x)}dx,f(x)=\frac{R}{(x^2+R^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$ And therefore $\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}*2 \Rightarrow \frac{\mu_0}{2\pi}$

Comment: @ガブリエルGabriel Integrals are linear, which means you can move in or out constants from the integral sign without changing its value. If you want, you can remove the constants; it does not affect the function being even or odd.

Comment: @ガブリエルGabriel I should have the constant factor $R$ into the constant $C$. Edited.